# the location don't works i don't know why

Tags: java, android, performance, location

Please any one help me. I want the app to show my location in 2 textviews, but it doesn't show the location.
And i want to know how to add the location in database and get it when i want.

Thanks for everyone will help me :)

---

```
public class Main2 extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private Location location;
    private TextView txt1;
    private TextView txt2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);


        txt1 = findViewById(R.id.tv_latitude);
        txt2 = findViewById(R.id.tv_longitude);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }


        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        onLocationChanged(location);


    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longi = location.getLongitude();
        double lati = location.getLatitude();
        txt1.setText("lati:" + lati);
        txt2.setText("longi" + longi);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }


}
```

---

manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

---

2 TextViews

```
    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_longitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="long"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_latitude"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:text="lat"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

Comment: locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
--Try this in your code and do some movement with device.

Comment: it didn't work with me .

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Add this permission, are you checking on emulator ?

Comment: no my samsung  phone

Comment: it works thanks :)

Comment: it works thanks :)

Comment: Glad to here that.